# Problem with className.indexOf()

Tags: jquery

i've got a problem with className.indexOf()

here's the code

```
$('#energie').click(function() {
     if(this.className.indexOf('active1, active2')!=-1){}
     else{
     if(this.className.indexOf('inactive1')!=-1){
     $('#navigation div').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass('active1');
     $(this).siblings().addClass('inactive2');
     }
     else {
     $('#navigation div').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass('active2');
     $(this).siblings().addClass('inactive1');
     }
             $("#maincontent > div:visible").fadeOut(300, function(){
         $("div.energiewende").fadeIn(450);
                  ]);
          }

  )};
```

the problem is, that if className of .this is active1 or active2 the else function will be triggered although it shouldn't.

Comment: You should be using the `hasClass` function - http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 7):

Your condition check is checking to see if you have "active1, active" as a string, even though that's not how class names are represented internally (they are just separated by space).

If you're using jQuery, you should use the `hasClass` function:

```
if($(this).hasClass('active1') || $(this).hasClass('active2'))
   // Do Stuff
```

Comment: [`is` could be better if you need to call `hasClass` more than once](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass#comment-40220179)

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` as you are using here is purely a method of strings and has nothign to do with CSS classes. That means `this.className.indexOf('active1, active2')` looks for the literal string `'active1, active2'` in the content of the class attribute. It won't look for `active1` and `active1` separately.

Since you are using jQuery, you should use it's `hasClass` method instead:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active1') || $(this).hasClass('active2')) {
   // ...
}
```